# into what format do I have to export lynis to in order to retain colorized output?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have successfully exported lynis' output in terminal to a .txt file but when I tried to show it in my laravel modal, the colour codes become boxes of unknown characters (like when you send chinese text but its not supported by the device.

I have tried exporting it to .odt, .rtf and so on but the result is the same.

what I expected (the [done] is in green)

```
- Checking profiles...                                      [ DONE ]
```

here's the actual result:

```
[2C- Checking profiles...[37C [ [1;32mDONE[0m ]
```

this is what I run in my ansible to get the output of lynis

```
./lynis audit system > /var/log/{{ inventory_hostname }}-lynis.txt
```

this is what I use in php to show the contents of the .txt

```
return nl2br(file_get_contents($path));
```

I checked the exported results in vim and it also shows

```
[2C- Checking profiles...[37C [ [1;32mDONE[0m ]
```

I know that .txt can't have coloured texts. so the question is which format should I use or how do I format it so that it can be shown with colours

Comment: https://github.com/sensiolabs/ansi-to-html

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer.

I use ansible to install epel-release and pip (the hosts are centos) then I install ansi2html via pip and do

```
./lynis audit system | ansi2html > /var/log/{{ inventory_hostname }}-lynis.html
```